# Berry's paradox with Godel encoding

Tags: paradoxes

I thought this is so obvious that people would have asked this question before, but for some reasons I can't find it. So here go:

We are working in PA. With Godel encoding, we can encode a FOL formula as a number. Further more, given a number, there exist FOL formula that allow us to: check whether that number is the encoding of a valid FOL formula; if it is a valid encoding, evaluate the encoded formula with a number; find the length of the formula and compare it with other numbers.

Hence we should be able to produce the FOL formula:

"x is the smallest number such that for all encoding of FOL formula that have length less than N that evaluate to true at an unique number, then x is not that number"

Here N stand for whatever an upper bound on the total length of the formula is going to be. In fact, N can be expressed by something that look like "(1+1)x(1+1)x...". Since this expression increase in length linearly while the number it expressed increase exponentially, eventually we can ensure that the number N actually is an upper bound on the length of the formula.

Hence it looks like Berry's paradox can apply. What is going on?

Comment: I am not a logician but I think Berry's Paradox cannot be applied since we only use FOL.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: I do in fact meant PA, but I can't quite see how it can't be formulated.

Comment: Hmm, sorry, I think I misspoke. If you write down a version of this statement that can actually be formulated in PA then you'll get a statement which is neither provable nor disprovable in PA; that is, you'll have proven the incompleteness theorem. This idea appears to be due to George Boolos.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: I don't see how provability have anything to do with this. The formula is either true or false, once you plug in a number. We can prove that exactly 1 number exist that satisfy the formula.

Answer (score 3):

The problem comes when you write

> . . . that evaluate to true at . . .

To express this in first-order logic, what you would need is a formula $\varphi$ of two variables such that for all natural numbers $m, n$, $\varphi(m, n)$ holds iff the formula with Godel number $m$ holds of $n$ in the standard model. This is impossible, by Tarski's theorem on the undefinability of truth.

Put another way, expressions of the relevant form ("The least natural number not first-order definable by a sentence with [property]") are **not** in fact definitions in first-order arithmetic. We can think of them as meaningful expressions in the context of arithmetic *using a logic stronger than first-order logic* (the general study of which is called "abstract model theory"), or as a first-order definition *within some larger structure* (say, in set theory), but we have to "go outside first-order arithmetic" somehow. And this prevents the paradox from working.

It's worth noting that we *can* get **restricted truth predicates**: for example, for each $k$, there is a formula $\psi_k$ of two variables such that for all natural numbers $m, n$, $\psi_k(m, n)$ holds iff $m$ is the Godel-number of a [$\Sigma^0_k$-formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetical_hierarchy#The_arithmetical_hierarchy_of_formulas) which holds of $n$. This lets us rigorously talk, in $\mathsf{PA}$ or similar, about the least number which is not definable **by a $\Sigma^0_k$ formula** of length $<$ [something really big]. But $\psi_k$, and consequently this "$\Sigma_k$-Berry definition," will be a $\Sigma^0_{k+1}$ formula. So this process never "catches its tail" and a genuine Berry *paradox* never arises.

Note that we can perform the same sort of "stratification" on the Liar paradox: while [self-reference *is* achievable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonal_lemma), the best approximation to the Liar we can get with a first-order sentence is something like "I am not a true $\Sigma_k$ sentence" - which is in fact true since it's not a $\Sigma_k$ sentence in the first place!

(Incidentally, these restricted truth predicates are quite useful in proof theory and computability theory, as are their [higher analogues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9vy_hierarchy) in set theory, so this isn't just an exercise in de-paradoxification.)

Comment: Also note that - similarly to the Liar - if we replace "truth" with some appropriately definable variation on truth (e.g. PA-provability), then the Berry *paradox* turns into a *theorem* of logic. In general, a ton of arguments in this area come from "de-paradoxifying," and almost invariably the thing that prevents the original paradox from actually kicking in is the undefinability of truth.